# Is possible to deployed SSDT 2017/2019 in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

We are currently working on a project to execute a wide range of data migration tasks and we are thinking on SSIS one of the component of Microsoft SQL Server. Currently, we have SQL Server 2014 Enterprise installed Database and SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT - BI 2014). Also, I found out that there are different version of SSDT - BI (2017, 2019) which is more advance than the previous one. Now, just wondering if possible to create and deploy a package build in the latest SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 to SQL Server 2014 version? Sorry, quiet new on this technology. Hope for some advice and recommendation from our SQL Experts here. Thanks in advance for your inputs. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install VS 2017 or 2019 and target 2014 for your version.  My VS 2019 install can target SSIS 2012 and higher.